# ngAnnotate - Warning: StringMap expected string key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gruntjs, uglifyjs, ng-annotate

I get this warning when using *Grunt* and *grunt-ng-annotate*.

There is no reference in the warning to where the error is in the file, which makes debugging it hard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The issue turned out to be use of ES6 notation, in this case arrow functions (**=>**), **default** parameters and **let**.

I haven't looked in detail as to why ngAnnotate doesn't support this.

To find where the issues were I overrode the ngAnnotate warning with grunt switch *--force* and later in the build uglify complained about the ES6 syntax with more detail.

Comment: Thx, you saved me some debugging :) best solution IMHO is to build everything with babel, and use `babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate`

Comment: To find the line number with the problem, use `--force` to push past ng-annotate. `uglify` will complain later, with an actual line number in the .tmp source code.

Answer (score 22):

Possible reasons:

- `() => {}`
- `{ value }`
- `let`
- `function (...args)`
- `function (defaultVar = false)`

Solutions:

- `function () {}`
- `{ value: value }`
- `var`
- `function (args)`
- `function (defaultVar) { defaultVar = (defaultVar === undefined) ? false : defaultVar }`

Comment: depending on where you use `...` the other solution would be to use `.concat()`

Answer (score 13):

I also faced the same problem but in my case, there was a different issue.

One of our team members has initialized function parameter to some default value. Something like the following.

```
$scope.functionName = function(defaultVar = false){ 
    //some code 
}
```

and in my gulp script, there was a line

```
.pipe(plugins.if(release, plugins.ngAnnotate()))
```

So when I have removed this line the build script automatically printed the error in console pointing to the exact file and line number where the error was.

Finally, I was able to solve it by removing that variable initialization code.

Hope this will help someone...

Comment: Thank you! This was the root cause for me too.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar issue caused by a destructuring assignment:

```
// the following line broke the build
const { name, gender, yearOfBirth, occupation } = profile;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31877984)